# Using to_datetime method in Dask on string similar to pandas

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I have case where I am creating pandas Timestamp object from string '2021-10-19 09:13:25.091'.
simple pd.to_datetime('2021-10-19 09:13:25.091') returns TIMESTAMP object. As moving to DASK tried doing same as follow with: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.to_datetime.html

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

logtimestamp = '2021-10-19 09:13:25.091'

print(dd.to_datetime(logtimestamp))
```

***But it raise exception: dask.dataframe.to_datetime does not support non-indexable arguments.***

However as per document: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.to_datetime.html

Parameters accepted are
argint, float, **str**, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series, DataFrame/dict-like

I am probably interpreting it wrong. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The Dask documentation page that you've linked to seems to be copied from [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). (Many dask docstring are, eg: [this one](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.applymap.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.applymap)).

There will be inconsistencies in `to_datetime` here and not everything in the docs page might be implemented in Dask. In your example, the `NotImplementedError` error is raised, which suggests this functionality doesn't exist in Dask.